# Is it possible to rewrite a SUM-GROUP-BY subquery into a single query? It's a shot on better performance

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'd like to optimize the following query.  I've noticed that I can reduce the time quite a bit by removing the subquery from `billing_payment_applied` in the LEFT-JOIN clause.  My question is whether it is possible to do somehow rewrite it without this subquery.

```
SELECT a, b, c, ...
  FROM billing_invoice_item 
  LEFT JOIN billing_statement
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(x), invoice_id 
       FROM billing_payment_applied
       WHERE invoice_id != 0  AND (apply_date <= now())
       GROUP BY invoice_id) AS BAL
  WHERE [...]
```

It seems to me that this would be possible if we can somehow put a condition on SUM().

What the query above is doing is getting the SUM() of invoices for each record previously collected.  I'm thinking of that as a function call.  Instead of making various function calls for each record, let's get all the data that the function call needs and do the SUM() later.  I'm going to need to be able to identify which values come from billing_payment_applied and which do not, but that's possible because a LEFT JOIN will produce NULL values when no records were found.  Also, SUM() will need to be able to sum only those that come from billing_payment_applied, but that also seems possible with a CASE-WHEN statement.

So, I wrote

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN BAL.id is NULL THEN 0 ELSE BAL.amount), ...
  FROM billing_invoice_item 
  LEFT JOIN billing_statement
  LEFT JOIN `billing_payments_applied` bpa on 
            bpa.invoice_id = stm.id 
        AND bpa.invoice_id != 0 
        AND (`apply_date` IS NOT NULL AND `apply_date` <= now())
  WHERE [...]
  GROUP BY bpa.invoice_id
```

But this produces a lot less records than the original query, so this can't be right.  What I thought it was equivalent isn't really.  Where is my misunderstanding?

**Original query**.  In case it helps, here's the original query.

```
SELECT
    `item`.`id` AS `id`,
                                 `inv`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,
                                 `item`.`sku` AS `sku`,
                                 `item`.`item_name` AS `item_name`,
                                 `item`.`price_ext` AS `item_price`,                                 
                                 ROUND( item.`price_ext` - ( item.`price_ext` * ( ( IFNULL( invbal.`amount_applied`, 0 ) * 100 ) / IFNULL( stm.`amount`, 0 ) ) ) / 100, 2 ) AS `item_price_balance`,
                                 `inv`.`invoice_number` AS `invoice_number`,
                                 `inv`.`invoice_date` AS `invoice_date`,
                                 `inv`.`due_date` AS `due_date`,
                                 CASE
                                    WHEN diritem.`type` = 'dues_membership_levels' THEN 'dues'
        WHEN diritem.`type` = 'hidden_commerce_dues' THEN 'dues'
        WHEN diritem.`type` = 'hidden_commerce_events' THEN 'events'
        WHEN diritem.`type` = 'hidden_finance_discounts' THEN 'finance'
        WHEN diritem.`type` = 'programs_course_products' THEN 'programs'
        WHEN diritem.`type` != '' THEN 'commerce'
        ELSE 'billing'
    END AS `origin`,
                                 IFNULL( diritem.`display_name`, `item`.`sku` ) AS `title`,
                                 diritem.`category` AS `category`,
                                 CONCAT( 'product_' , IFNULL( diritem.`id`, `item`.`sku` ) ) AS `product_id`,
                                 '' AS `start_date`,
                                 '' AS `ticket_name`,
                                 '' AS `ticket_type`
FROM
    `billing_invoice_item` AS `item`
INNER JOIN `billing_invoice` AS `inv` ON
    item.`invoice_id` = inv.`id`
    AND inv.`invoice_type` = ''
LEFT JOIN `billing_statement` AS `stm` ON
    stm.`invoice_number` = inv.`invoice_number`
    AND stm.`trans_id` = inv.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM( `amount` * -1 ) AS `amount_applied`,
        `invoice_id`
    FROM
        `billing_payments_applied`
    WHERE
        `invoice_id` != 0
        AND ( `apply_date` IS NOT NULL
            AND `apply_date` <= '2023-05-02 23:59:59' )
    GROUP BY
        `invoice_id`) AS invbal ON
    invbal.`invoice_id` = stm.`id`
LEFT JOIN `shopping_sku` sku ON
    sku.`sku` = item.`sku`
    AND sku.`origin` = 'directory'
LEFT JOIN `directory_items` diritem ON
    sku.`product_id` = diritem.`id`
WHERE
    item.`sku` NOT LIKE 'events_%'
    AND IF( inv.`due_date` < IFNULL( stm.`trans_date`, inv.`invoice_date` )
                                ,
    inv.`due_date`
                                ,
    IFNULL( stm.`trans_date`, inv.`invoice_date` ) ) <= '2023-05-02 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Probably not relevant,  but you've got cross joins in your first two queries, at least the way you've put them here.

Comment: An INNER JOIN is a CROSS JOIN?  Like you, I'm not sure that is relevant.  I really meant to write `INNER JOIN` there --- because the original query is like that.  Are you seeing something I'm not?  I'm not sure.  Thank you for the verification.

Comment: You have no on clause here - `billing_invoice_item  LEFT JOIN billing_statement LEFT JOIN ...`. It may be in your original query tho.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck optimising by applying relevant indexes rather than trying to rewrite the query to avoid the subquery. e.g. an index on `invoice_id, apply_date, amount` should make the subquery much more efficient (although will of course of an impact on writes). Indexing is not an exact science and will always depend on your specific scenario.

Comment: It depends on the types of relationships. (It's safe to GROUP BY in a subquery before joining.)

Comment: It's impossible to help you optimize unless we know your ON clauses for your JOINs.  If you don't know what that means, *please* find out. And, to help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: I still see no `ON` for `LEFT JOIN billing_statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about *LEFT*?  That says that data in the "right" table could be missing, and you are willing to get NULLs in place of the SUM, etc.  (And you might want to do `COALESCE(...)` to turn it into `0` in the outer query.)

What you have *should* make one pass over `billing_payment_applied` to get all the available SUMs (after filtering by `WHERE`).  This index *may* help:

```
INDEX(invoice_id, apply_date, x)
```

Another way to write the query, but not necessarily any faster in your case:

```
SELECT  ...
        COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(x) ... WHERE ... ), 0) AS bal,   -- No GROUP BY
    WHERE ...;
```

(Without knowing which columns are in which tables, I don't see how to include `billing_statement`.  Please qualify column names with the tables they are in.)